# Android: Cardslib Errors when referencing library

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, cardslib, android-cards

So I wanted to implement the Cardslib from Gabriele Mariotti and I followed [his steps](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/BUILD.md#reference-this-project-as-a-library-in-eclipse) to successfully add cardslib as a library to my project. But as soon as I add the library reference I get these errors:

```
G:\UI Kit\Android Sample Projects\cardslib-master\cardslib-master\library-cards\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:23: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native'.

G:\UI Kit\Android Sample Projects\cardslib-master\cardslib-master\library-cards\src\main\res\values-v16\styles.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native'.

G:\UI Kit\Android Sample Projects\cardslib-master\cardslib-master\library-cards\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native.content_outer_layout'.

G:\UI Kit\Android Sample Projects\cardslib-master\cardslib-master\library-cards\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native'.

G:\UI Kit\Android Sample Projects\cardslib-master\cardslib-master\library-cards\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:55: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native'.

G:\UI Kit\Android Sample Projects\cardslib-master\cardslib-master\library-cards\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:64: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native'.

G:\UI Kit\Android Sample Projects\cardslib-master\cardslib-master\library-cards\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:23: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native'.

G:\UI Kit\Android Sample Projects\cardslib-master\cardslib-master\library-cards\src\main\res\values-v16\styles.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native'.

G:\UI Kit\Android Sample Projects\cardslib-master\cardslib-master\library-cards\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native.content_outer_layout'.

G:\UI Kit\Android Sample Projects\cardslib-master\cardslib-master\library-cards\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native'.

G:\UI Kit\Android Sample Projects\cardslib-master\cardslib-master\library-cards\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:55: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native'.

G:\UI Kit\Android Sample Projects\cardslib-master\cardslib-master\library-cards\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:64: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native'.
```

Has anyone else faced these errors before? My main project's android min sdk is at 14 and target is at 18. The library requires a minimum of 14 and targeted at 21 as mentioned on his site.

Help out please?

Comment: Are you using api21 to compile?